# (Updated) Trying to edit the behaviour of toggle function in tablesorter with a nested table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tablesorter

(This post has been updated for clarity and more of my findings.)

I'm currently using the tablesorter functions `toggle` and `tablesorter-childRow` to make a table that has a child row that can be hidden and expanded by clicking 'toggle' on the primary row like [this example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html). However, the child row contains a nested table where the first row also contains a `toggle` function that can hide or expand all the remaining rows of that nested table. Here is my table [in action](https://jsfiddle.net/seancwu/1v6ph4ck/4/).

Currently, the `toggle` functions all work fine in the sense that they are able to hide and expand the rows that I want to. However, if I click on the primary row's `toggle` function (the row with Category I), the function expands the entire nested table. **I would like the `toggle` function on the primary role to only expand the first row of the nested table only (the row with Category II).**

For my script, I used the default script found on the `cssChildRow` configuration [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html). What I tried to do is to give the rows that I want expanded its own html class (in the fiddle they are marked with `<td class="show">`). Then I edited the to script function to `.find('.show')` instead of the default `.find('td')`, but this did not work. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks for everyone's help!

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();



  $(".tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
      cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow"
    })

  $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click', function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.tablesorter-childRow)').find('.show').toggle();

    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the second table has its own table-layout, its columns won't match its parent table's columns. give it at least width:100% to fill its entire td parent. but that won't be enough. That is probably closer to what you try to do https://jsfiddle.net/dewz2pub/

Comment: Thanks for the reply  However I was asking about the behaviour of the toggle function (I've updated the post for more clarity). The table in my new fiddle now resembles more like the table you posted. But the child row still has a nested table because that's the only way for the top toggle function (the toggle on the row with Category I) to be able to hide every row underneath without using the secondary toggle function (the toggle on the row with Category II).